# Spring Security taglib doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, spring-security

I got problem.. in my WEB-INF/lib I got jars and all of them are spring jars in version 4.2.4, but there is two exceptions: spring-security-config has 4.0.3 and spring-security-taglibs too

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.damian.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0"> 
<display-name>OnlineShop</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

stacktrace:

```
 sty 09, 2016 9:10:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve   invoke
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context  with  path [/OnlineShop] threw exception [An exception occurred processing  JSP page /WEB-INF/Main.jsp at line 54

51:             style="text-decoration: none; color: #000">WALLETS</a>
52:     </h2>
53:     
54: <sec:authorize url="/logged">
55: <div class="cart">
56:     <a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/cart.html"
57:             style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Cart </a>


 Stacktrace:] with root cause
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionHandler
at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderB    ase.java:1167)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:    127)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(Defa    ultInstanceManager.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:136)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool.get(TagHandlerPool.java:121)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Main_jsp._jspx_meth_sec_005fauthorize_005f0(Main_jsp.java:215)
at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.Main_jsp._jspService(Main_jsp.java:172)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:719)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:465)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:390)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:317)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Main.jsp:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>

<sec:authorize url="/logged">
<div class="cart">
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/cart.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> Cart </a>
</div>
</sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `spring-security-core` in your classpath

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't use Maven...I added spring-security-core but still doesn't work

Comment: This class(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionHandler) is for this spring-security-core package, double check if you have it in your war/WEB-INF/lib